# How To Make Dynamic Link On Email in ASP.NET Core From Environment variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Example: `<a href= example.company.com >Contact Us</a>`

```
Hi <a href="http://example.company.com/Contact/">Contact Us</a> Thank you.
```

```
Hi <a href= <%= Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("example.com") %> " > Contact Us </a>  Thank you.
```

Its not working as expected.

Could someone help me to fix this.

Comment: Do you have the `mailto:` prefix in your environment variable's value?

Comment: Please be specific over what you mean by "not working as expected". What were you seeing, and how did that differ from your expectations?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify your question, specifically *Its not working as expected.*  Can you [edit] share a [mcve] showing what you did and tell us what happened vs what you wanted?  See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

> Hi <a href= <%= Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("example.com") %> "> Contact Us Thank you.

Do you mean the email body looks like the above? If that is the case, please check the related code about how to generate the email body, the issue relates to it.

You can refer to the following code to generate the email body (here I get value from configuration, you can change it to get value from Environment):

```
 //build the mail body and add the hyperlink
 string mailbody = "<h1>Hi <a href= '" + _config.GetSection("contacturl").Value + "' > Contact Us </a> Thank you.</h1>";
```

More detail information, you could refer the following sample:

```
        string to = "sender@hotmail.com"; //To address    
        string from = "receiver@hotmail.com"; //From address    
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

        //build the mail body and add the hyperlink
        string mailbody = "<h1>Hi <a href= '" + _config.GetSection("contacturl").Value + "' > Contact Us </a> Thank you.</h1>";
        message.Subject = "Contact Us";

        //set the mail body format
        message.Body = mailbody;
        message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true; //

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587); //outlook smtp    
        System.Net.NetworkCredential basicCredential1 = new
        System.Net.NetworkCredential("sender email", "password");
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = basicCredential1;
        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        client.Dispose();
```

Need to add the following reference:

```
using System.Net;    
using System.Net.Mail; 
using System.Text;
```

The received email is this:

[image]

**[Note]** In the above sample, I'm sending the email via the outlook email, so when create the SmtpClient instance, I use the outlook smtp and set the port to 587, if you want to send an email using another SMTP Server, you can refer the following table:

[image]